# libdoc in java library for RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I have generated libdoc, using command `jython -m robot.libdoc --version 1.0 RFKeywords.java RFKeywords.html`, also I have .jar file, that contains Keywords. I added this .jar file into RobotFramework project like library, but I can't see any documentation, even I have in the source. 
With this generated documentation, how I can add this documentation in jar file?
Currently I can see keyword documentation form RED plugin
[image]

I want to see documentation like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you would like to see such documentation as "Wait Until Page Contains" for keywords.Sikuli in RED under Project Explorer ,am I right? This can be done in couple of ways in RED.

- If you include such resource/library in testfile and do autodiscovery/quickfix (it should be done automatically on save action), libdoc will be generated for that entry.
- Library can be added manually to red.xml (double click on red.xml, under tab: Referenced Library add proper file).
- Libdoc as xml can be also included in red.xml (this is handy when you don't have actual lib installed in your system )

Comment: Currently I added like Library and I can see the documentation if I click in project explorer, but this is not what I want. Well, I want when I'm typing some keyword in test.robot file, the documentation to be there (after pressing Ctrl + Space).

Comment: can you share your files (jar file or sources) on RED github page github.com/nokia/red so we could understand better?